# input moves left on hovering another element

Tags: html, css

```css
.mdcancel {
  float: left;
}

#mdedit input[type='text'] {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 7px auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.mdcancel:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class='md' id='mdedit'>
  <input type='text' id='inpname'>
  <br>
  <div class='mdcancel'>CANCEL</div>
</div>
```

Type anything inside `inpname` and then hover `.mdcancel`.

You'll see that `inpname` moves left.

This won't happen if I change `.mdcancel:hover`  -  `opacity:0.8` to some another -  `background:gold` for example.

[jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/20523/)

Comment: It's all about the property `float:left;` of the class `.mdcancel`.
Without it everything works.

Comment: @VitalySurkov, but keeping `float:left` and changing `hover` also solves.

Comment: Maybe then use `color: rgba (0,0,0, .8);` instead of `opacity: 0.8`?

Comment: @VitalySurkov I have a lot of solutions, but I'm interesting what is the reason of the strange behaviour.

Comment: Since it happens neither in Firefox nor in IE, it's probably a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @MrLister, probably you're right. Do you know what is the procedure to tell Google about this bug?

Comment: @bonaca Yes, here is the Issues list: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list But I must admit I'm terrible with searching lists like that, so I haven't found it this specific bug report has been filed yet. What I do see is that the problem is present on both Windows and Linux, and it still exists in the latest Canary.

Comment: i have some idea but not enough to explain ... we know that when the opacity is less than 1 we create a new stacking context so combined with the float it may create this bug